# php not echoing back radio value

Tags: php, html

I cannot get the radio value's to echo back as checked within the conditional block, it's got to be an issue with my syntax. I know you don't have the full code but I can assure you 100% that the conditions are all true. What am I missing?

```
<?php if(!empty($userRow[insurance_name2])):?>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="insurance-name2"
                                                       name="insurance-name2"
                                                       placeholder="Insurance Name"
                                                       value="<?php echo $userRow[insurance_name2] ?>">
                                                <input name="insurance-network-option2" type='radio'
                                                       value="in-network" <?= ($userRow['insurance_option2'] == "in-network") ? 'checked' : '' ?>>In-Network
                                                <input name="insurance-network-option2" type='radio'
                                                       value="out-of-network" <?= ($userRow['insurance_option2'] == "out-of-network") ? 'checked' : '' ?>>Out-Of-Network
                                                <br>
                                                <br>
                                            <?php endif?>
```

Comment: What is the HTML source you get for that? And what does `echo $userRow['insurance_option2']` yield?

Comment: http://ideone.com/Lr17So works for me, are you sure of your variables?

Comment: @Dagon that's because you don't have it wrapped in the conditional block, `<?php if(!empty($userRow['insurance_name2'])):?>` `<?php endif ?>`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php if(!empty($userRow['insurance_name2'])):?>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="insurance-name2" name="insurance-name2"    placeholder="Insurance Name" value="<?= $userRow['insurance_name2']; ?>" />

 <input name="insurance-network-option2" type='radio' value="in-network" <?= ($userRow['insurance_option2'] == "in-network") ? 'checked' : '' ?>/>In-Network

 <input name="insurance-network-option2" type='radio' value="out-of-network" <?= ($userRow['insurance_option2'] ==  "out-of-network") ? 'checked' : '' ?> />Out-Of-Network
<?php endif ?>
```

You did forget some quotes and to close the input tag. which is what I changed.
If it doesn't solve your problem let me know what errors you're getting.

Comment: Still not coming back. Funny thing is, outside of this `<?php if(!empty($userRow['insurance_name2'])):?>` It works. But that's not because the the condition is false, otherwise it wouldn't echo back anything at all, and everything shows up but the radio values checked appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Realized my issue. Beneath I had a hidden div containing the same code as the block within the php conditional. Reason being, if the element exists in the database, I wanted it to display. Otherwise, if I user clicked a certain button to add an insurance name and network option, it would remove the hidden field.

So I rearranged the code like so, and called removeAttribute method from within the php block. Works perfectly.

```
<div class="hidden" id="insurance2">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="insurance-name2"
                                                   name="insurance-name2"
                                                   placeholder="Insurance Name"
                                                   value="<?php echo $userRow[insurance_name2] ?>">
                                            <!--                                                                <br>-->
                                            <input name="insurance-network-option2" type='radio'
                                                   value="in-network" <?= ($userRow['insurance_option2'] == "in-network") ? 'checked' : '' ?>>In-Network
                                            <input name="insurance-network-option2" type='radio'
                                                   value="out-of-network" <?= ($userRow['insurance_option2'] == "out-of-network") ? 'checked' : '' ?>>Out-Of-Network
                                            <br>
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                            <!--//insurance two-->
                                            <?php if(!empty($userRow[insurance_name2])):?>
                                                <?php echo"<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('insurance2').removeAttribute('class');</script>"?>
                                            <?php endif?>
```

Comment: so unanswerable based on the code provided in the question, this should be deleted as it will be of zero help to any one in the future.